# How to make Material-UI Snackbar not take up the whole screen width using anchorOrigin?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a class in React which uses an input field which is part of the website header:
[image]

If the input is invalid then I want to display a snackbar. I'm using [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/api/snackbar/) components.

The problem is I defined `anchorOrigin` to be center and top as per Material-UI API. However the snackbar takes up the whole screen width while I want it to only take up the top center location of the screen. My message is quite short, for example "Value invalid" but if it's longer then I should be able to use newlines. I'm not sure if there's some setting in Material-UI API to alter this (I couldn't find one) or I need to use CSS.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import SnackbarMessage from './SnackbarMessage.js';

const classes = theme => ({
  inputRoot: {
    color: 'inherit',
    width: '100%',
  },
  inputInput: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit,
    paddingRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit,
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 10,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: 120,
      '&:focus': {
        width: 200,
      },
    },
  }
});

class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    appId: '',
    snackBarOpen: false
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <InputBase
          placeholder="Search…"
          classes={{
            root: classes.inputRoot,
            input: classes.inputInput,
          }}
          value={'test'} />
        <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'center'
        }}
        open={true}
        autoHideDuration={5000}
      >
        <SnackbarMessage
          variant="warning"
          message={"test message"}
        />
      </Snackbar>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see import statements for `Snackbar` and `SnackbarMessage` ... How is the above code even running? Also, in the material-ui examples for `Snackbar` it does not take the entire screen width. Try to inspect the element and see where the 100% width is coming from.

Comment: @o4ohel I found from Chrome's inspect tool that `SnackbarMessage` has the following CSS: `@media (max-width: 959.95px)
<style>…</style>
.MuiSnackbarContent-root-169 {
    flex-grow: 1;
}`. When I disable `flex-grow` the snackbar doesn't take up the whole width. I tried adding style to `SnackbarMessage` to manually set `flex-grow` to 0 but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material-UI set Snackbars to full viewport-width below the breakpoint "md" (600px).
You can use overrides (https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/) and set new values to the default CSS classes of the component described in the components API (i.e. https://material-ui.com/api/snackbar/). So you can override the class `anchorOriginTopCenter` as follows:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  anchorOriginTopCenter: {
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      top: "your value/function here",
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  },
  root: {
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      borderRadius: 4,
      minWidth: "your value / function here",
    },
  },
});
```

The first objects overrides the default class {anchorOriginTopCenter}, the second 'root' is applied to first element in your snackbar (probably a 'div').

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if we can add some style to the component anchor origin field. I think the div needs to be managed using CSS. It's an anchor, not style.

```
<Snakbar 
   className = "my-snakbar"
   {/*All your other stuff*/}
   >
{//Stuff}
</Snakbar>
```

CSS

```
.my-snakbar {
  width: 200px;
  //Maybe use flexbox for positioning then
}
```

Let me know your thoughts

Daniel

Improved Answer

Code copied from origional question and modified

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';

const classes = theme => ({
  inputRoot: {
    color: 'inherit',
    width: '100%',
  },
  inputInput: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit,
    paddingRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit,
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 10,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: 120,
      '&:focus': {
        width: 200,
      },
    },
  }
});

class ComingSoon extends Component {

  render() {

    const styles = {
      container: {
        position: "fixed",
        top: "0px",
        width: "100%",
        height: "30px"
      },
      snakbar: {
        background: "black",
        color: "white",
        width: "100px",
        height: "100%",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignContent: "center",
        margin: "0 auto"
      }
    };

    return (
      <div className = "snakbar-container" style = {styles.container}>
        <Snackbar
          className = "my-snakbar"
          style = {styles.snakbar}
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: 'top',
            horizontal: 'center'
          }}
          open={true}
          autoHideDuration={5000}
          >
            <span>My Message</span>
        </Snackbar>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ComingSoon;
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Let me know if this helped

Daniel

Comment: This didn't help.

Comment: I amended answer and made it work. Screenshot demonstrates. Also in the comments above, it mentions that the demos on the material UI site show how style is handled.

Comment: Your second suggestion didn't work either, moreover even in the image your provided you can see that it didn't work (the message is in the left top corner while in the OP it says "I defined anchorOrigin to be center and top").

Comment: I see. that's an easy fix. Ill amend right now on fly

Comment: That should do it. I imagine there is a more professional way through. But that CSS will do it